# Image not being displayed in layout preview

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

Im making a quiz app, and want this bulb image to be present throughout.

I tried adding an ImageView in the layouts, got it to show on the preview, 
But when I run the app, image is not shown.

I tried changing the XML code from 
`app:srcCompat="@drawable/bulb"`  to `android:src="@drawable/bulb"`
(crashed my app)

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:indeterminate="false" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/progress_bar"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:id="@+id/score"
        android:textColor="@color/colorText"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:text="@string/initial_score"
        android:padding="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/question_text_view"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:text="@string/question_1"
        android:textColor="@color/colorText"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    **<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bulbimage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="40dp"
        android:paddingTop="60dp"
        android:paddingRight="40dp"
        android:paddingBottom="50dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/bulb"
        android:contentDescription=""/>**

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_above="@id/score"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/true_button"
            android:text="@string/true_button"
            android:textColor="@color/colorText"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:background="@color/colorTrueButton"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:id="@+id/false_button"
            android:text="@string/false_button"
            android:background="@color/colorFalseButton"
            android:textColor="@color/colorText"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post the stacktrace error

Comment: What is the type of your image drawable bulb? Is it SVG or PNG?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*If no Syntactical error is present in the code,(Either in the main.java file or the activity.XML file)->*

**Simply reduce the size of the image being used.
(Either by cropping or compressing)**

Detailed logic ->
The maximum size of a Bitmap will vary from device to device, depending on the heap space available. The heap space required as a minimum on any device with Google Play is 16 MB.

The rest of your app also runs in the same heap space, so the entire heap is not available for a single Bitmap.

Additionally, the size of the bitmap will vary depending on the color format and height and width.

The best policy is to load only the size of the bitmap required for that screen size into memory, and nothing bigger.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if the image is in drawable folder not in drawable-21 or anything..
2. Try to add  height and width (like 100dp)  to image.
3. Or just check if image is too large!!

Comment: Hi, thanks, But it turned that the image was too large, cropping it solved the problem! Any idea on the limit of the image size?

Comment: @varungupta write it as an answer so the next people who search of it can see :)

Comment: Yes. Sometimes it won't give any errors  on emulators like Nox but it wont work on actual device.

Comment: Why did you put ** around your view

```xml
**<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bulbimage"/>**
```

Comment: ** is not in the actual code. In stack overflow, I bolded this section of the code, so it remained like this! (with a **)

Comment: @varungupta you can check the edited answer and close this question by accepting the Solution!!